# Unable to create printers on Windows 2008 using WMI Class

Tags: powershell, printing, powershell-2.0

When using the below code to create printer on Windows 2008 servers to create the printers

```
`function CreatePrinterPort { 
$server = $args[0] 
$port = ([WMICLASS]“\\$server\ROOT\cimv2:Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort").createInstance() 
$port.Name= $args[1] 
$port.SNMPEnabled=$false 
$port.Protocol=2 
$port.HostAddress= $args[2] 
$port.Put() 
}

function CreatePrinter { 
$server = $args[0] 
$print = ([WMICLASS]“\\$server\ROOT\cimv2:Win32_Printer”).createInstance() 
$print.Drivername = $args[1] 
$print.PortName = $args[2] 
$print.Shared = $true 
$print.Published = $false 
$print.Sharename = $args[3] 
$print.Location = $args[4] 
$print.Comment = $args[5]
$print.DeviceID=$args[2]  
$print.Put() 
}

$printers = Import-Csv “C:\printers.csv”

foreach ($printer in $printers) { 
CreatePrinterPort $printer.Printserver $printer.Portname $printer.IPAddress 
CreatePrinter $printer.Printserver $printer.Driver $printer.Portname $printer.Sharename $printer.Location $printer.Comment $printer.Printername 
}'
```

I am getting the following error. The port creation function is working.

```
"IsSingleton   : False

Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "Generic failure "
At line:23 char:1
+ $print.Put()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException"
```

I have importing all the details from a CSV file and it contains all the information.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to create the printer on a remote computer or the local computer?

Comment: Have you considered using the `Set-WMIInstance` or updated `New-CIMInstance` commands to do this? Also, you really need to look into advanced functions. It could make what you're doing better.

Comment: Creating the printers locally. I can create them remotely also if that is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're both doing this the hard way, and didn't read the MSDN page for the [Win32_Printer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363(v=vs.85).aspx). It says in the remarks that you have to enable the SeDriverUpdate privilege before you can issue the Put method, so I have a feeling that's where you're getting your error from.

Next, use the `Set-WMIInstance` cmdlet, or the newer 'New-CIMInstance` if you can. Calling the classes directly is possible I'm sure, but if the server is local it won't enable the privileges that you need to create a printer.

Lastly, you could make your function better if you made it an advanced function, and allowed piped data. Check this out:

```
function CreatePrinter { 
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('Printserver')]
    $Server,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('Driver')]
    $Drivername,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    $PortName,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    $Sharename,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    $Location,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    $Comment,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('IPAddress')]
    $HostAddress,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('PrinterName')]
    $Name
)
PROCESS{
    $PortArgs = @{
        Name = $PortName
        SNMPEnabled = $false
        Protocol = 2
        HostAddress = $HostAddress
    }
    Set-WmiInstance -Class Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort -Arguments $PortArgs -ComputerName $Server -PutType UpdateOrCreate -EnableAllPrivileges

    $PrinterArgs = @{
        Drivername = $Drivername
        PortName = $PortName
        Shared = $true
        Published = $false
        Sharename = $Sharename
        Location = $Location
        Comment = $Comment
        DeviceID = $PortName
        Name = $Name
    }
    Set-WmiInstance -Class Win32_Printer -Arguments $CmdArgs -ComputerName $Server -PutType UpdateOrCreate -EnableAllPrivileges
}
}
```

That creates the port, and then the printer. I suppose you could split it into two functions, but do you really see needing one without the other? Plus you can pipe your CSV data directly into it like this:

```
Import-CSV "C:\printers.csv" | CreatePrinter
```

That's it, that will create ports and printers for all records in the CSV. Plus I used the UpdateOrCreate enum, so if something isn't right you could correct the CSV and just run it again to refresh the settings to the correct settings without having to worry about deleting old copies and making new copies of things.

Comment: I tried running the above code but got the following error.

Set-WmiInstance : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
At line:45 char:20
+     Set-WmiInstance <<<<  -Class Win32_Printer -Arguments $CmdArgs -ComputerName $Server -PutType UpdateOrCreate -EnableAllPrivileges
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (UpdateOrCreate:PutType) [Set-WmiInstance], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateOnlyFlagNotSpecifiedWithClassPath,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetWmiInstance

Comment: This is the powerhsell version I am using

Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : c8d9cb41-ca33-4848-9e07-3c78596ad4b2
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEOptions
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Comment: Running it as admin only. The earlier script works flawlessly on Windows 2012. In windows 2008 I am able tor create ports so i think that calling the class should not be the problem. I am totally clueless to why this is happening.

Comment: Do it from a remote machine and see if you still get the error.